# Anyone use Pyjamas (pyjs) python to javascript compiler (like GWT..)

Tags: javascript, python, gwt

Has any one used this? I don't have a large background in Javascript and this lib looks like it may speed things along.

www.pyjs.org

Comment: Why the downvotes? I would also like the status of this library please. Could be incredible if it is mature.

Comment: I can tell you about mine. You don't have any specific question about the "fraamework" and look pretty much like blatant advertising. At least you could have asked "Why do I get xyz error while using pyjamas... BTW this is a python to javascript... etc. etc. "

Comment: The question ("Has anyone used this?") really doesn't require the extra detail. If you've used it, you know what it is. If you haven't, then your poorly informed answer probably won't be very helpful.

Answer (score 9):

yep. me.  i'm the lead developer.  drop by on groups.google.com "pyjamas-dev" and say hello.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, I've used. It's amazing! I think it's much easier to use than the Java-based GWT. I found the Google Code wiki on it very practical: http://code.google.com/p/pyjamas/w/list

If you're just starting out with it, then definitely check out the showcase: http://pyjs.org/showcase/Showcase.html for usable snippets/widgets

As of now, it is not supported on M$ Windows, but runs beautifully on Linux.

Answer (score 1):

yes it works fine on windows (it's a compiler: you just need python, to run the conversion to javascript).  but if you're thinking of pyjamas-desktop, 0.6 added support for MSHTML as one of the engines, so that works too.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. I've used pyjs to build minesweeper game: http://pymines.appspot.com/

Comment: it's wonderful! Could you please post a tutorial on how you did it? Thanks!

Comment: i was also curious, found it as part of the [examples](http://pyjs.org/examples/), the source code is available [here](https://github.com/pyjs/pyjs/tree/master/examples/minesweeper/).